# Implicit linsolve() in Sympy and then lambdify

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I'm asking is it possible to get `np.linalg.solve()` out of the `lambdify` on an expression involving solving?

For example, let

```
from sympy import MatrixSymbol, linsolve, lambdify

A = MatrixSymbol('A', 3, 3)
b = MatrixSymbol('b', 3, 1)

func = lambdify((A, b), linsolve((A, b)), modules="numpy")
```

Is it possible to generate the `func(A, b) = np.linalg.solve(A, b)`?

The above code for sure does not work. It will first fail at `linsolve((A, b))`.

My attempt would be somehow mark `linsolve((A, b))` as an implicit expression so that `lambdify` can recognize it and thus link it with `np.linalg.solve`. But I don't find if `sympy` support this.

Comment: Your error is in `linsolve((A,b))`, not the `lambdify`.  When you get failures like this, please show the error with traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function `sympy.codegen.matrix_nodes.MatrixSolve` instead of `sympy.linsolve`.

```py
from sympy import MatrixSymbol, lambdify
from sympy.codegen.matrix_nodes import MatrixSolve

A = MatrixSymbol('A', 3, 3)
b = MatrixSymbol('b', 3, 1)


func = lambdify((A, b), MatrixSolve(A, b), modules="numpy")
```

Comment: How do you verify your `func` really calls `np.linalg.solve()`?

Comment: Actually, it can never call `np.linalg.solve` as can be seen from the source `sympy.printing.pycode`, where contains all the functions that sympy supports. Using the equation x=A**(-1)*b is the easiest way to make it work as `np.linalg.solve`, otherwise you may have to code your own printer.

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/9e8f62e059d83178c1d8a1e19acac5473bdbf1c1/sympy/printing/pycode.py#L695  I found there is `np.linalg.solve` printer. Do you know how to call it?

Comment: I think I've found the answer here； https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/codegen.html?highlight=numpyprinter#sympy.codegen.matrix_nodes.MatrixSolve  Would you like to elaborate your answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Sorry I hadn't update my sympy to-date. I'll change my answer at once.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I've rewritten my answer. The function MatrixSolve works.

Comment: `print(func.__doc__)` shows the resulting numpy code.

Answer (score 1):

With `MatrixSolve`, `lambdify` performs a simple lexical replacement:

```
In [87]: MatrixSolve(A,b)
Out[87]: MatrixSolve(MatrixSymbol(Str('A'), Integer(3), Integer(3)), vector=MatrixSymbol(Str('b'), Integer(3), Integer(1)))

In [88]: func = lambdify((A, b), MatrixSolve(A, b), modules="numpy")

In [89]: func
Out[89]: <function _lambdifygenerated(A, b)>

In [90]: func?
Signature: func(A, b)
Docstring:
Created with lambdify. Signature:

func(A, b)

Expression:

MatrixSolve(A, vector=b)

Source code:

def _lambdifygenerated(A, b):
    return (solve(A, b))
```

Or use `print(func.__doc__)` to display that doc if not in `ipython/isympy`.

---

Your original problem was with using `sympy.linsolve`:

```
In [81]: linsolve((A,b))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-9ddeeeb0f242> in <module>
----> 1 linsolve((A,b))

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/solveset.py in linsolve(system, *symbols)
   2630         if not isinstance(system[0], MatrixBase):
   2631             if sym_gen or not symbols:
-> 2632                 raise ValueError(filldedent('''
   2633                     When passing a system of equations, the explicit
   2634                     symbols for which a solution is being sought must

ValueError: 
When passing a system of equations, the explicit symbols for which a
solution is being sought must be given as a sequence, too.
```